# Struts2 json model

Tags: json, model, struts2

I get the following problems when enter my action:

**Struts Problem Report**

Struts has detected an unhandled exception:

**Messages:**

```
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
 org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
 org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException:
 org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

**File:**

model/Empresa.java 
Line number: 34

//ACTION

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private SincronizaService service = new SincronizaServiceImp();
  //Your result List
  private List<Sincroniza>      gridModel;

  //get how many rows we want to have into the grid - rowNum attribute in the grid
  private Integer             rows             = 0;

  //Get the requested page. By default grid sets this to 1.
  private Integer             page             = 0;

  // sorting order - asc or desc
  private String              sord;

  // get index row - i.e. user click to sort.
  private String              sidx;

  // Search Field
  private String              searchField;

  // The Search String
  private String              searchString;

  // he Search Operation ['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','bn','in','ni','ew','en','cn','nc']
  private String              searchOper;

  // Your Total Pages
  private Integer             total            = 0;

  // All Record
  private Integer             records          = 0;
  public String execute() throws Exception
  {

    int to = (rows * page);
    int from = to - rows;


    //Count Rows (select count(*) from custumer)
    records = 5;//CustumerDAO.count();

    //Your logic to search and select the required data.
    gridModel = service.lista();//CustumerDAO.find(from, to);

    //calculate the total pages for the query
    total =(int) Math.ceil((double)records / (double)rows);

    return SUCCESS;
  }

  public String getJSON() throws Exception
  {
    return execute();
  }

public List<Sincroniza> getGridModel() {
    return gridModel;
}

public void setGridModel(List<Sincroniza> gridModel) {
    this.gridModel = gridModel;
}

public Integer getRows() {
    return rows;
}

public void setRows(Integer rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
}

public Integer getPage() {
    return page;
}

public void setPage(Integer page) {
    this.page = page;
}

public String getSord() {
    return sord;
}

public void setSord(String sord) {
    this.sord = sord;
}

public String getSidx() {
    return sidx;
}

public void setSidx(String sidx) {
    this.sidx = sidx;
}

public String getSearchField() {
    return searchField;
}

public void setSearchField(String searchField) {
    this.searchField = searchField;
}

public String getSearchString() {
    return searchString;
}

public void setSearchString(String searchString) {
    this.searchString = searchString;
}

public String getSearchOper() {
    return searchOper;
}

public void setSearchOper(String searchOper) {
    this.searchOper = searchOper;
}

public Integer getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(Integer total) {
    this.total = total;
}

public Integer getRecords() {
    return records;
}

public void setRecords(Integer records) {
    this.records = records;
}
```

//MODEL

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Integer idempresa;
private String descripcion;
private String abreviacion;
private String alterno_id;
private Date fecha_alta;
private Date fecha_cambios;
private Date fecha_baja;

public Empresa(int idempresa, String descripcion, String abreviacion,
        String alterno_id, Date fecha_alta, Date fecha_cambios,
        Date fecha_baja) {
    super();
    this.idempresa = idempresa;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.abreviacion = abreviacion;
    this.alterno_id = alterno_id;
    this.fecha_alta = fecha_alta;
    this.fecha_cambios = fecha_cambios;
    this.fecha_baja = fecha_baja;
}

public Empresa(){}

public int getIdempresa() {
    return idempresa;//THIS IS LINE 34
}
public void setIdempresa(int idempresa) {
    this.idempresa = idempresa;
}
public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}
public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}
public String getAbreviacion() {
    return abreviacion;
}
public void setAbreviacion(String abreviacion) {
    this.abreviacion = abreviacion;
}
public String getAlterno_id() {
    return alterno_id;
}
public void setAlterno_id(String alterno_id) {
    this.alterno_id = alterno_id;
}
public Date getFecha_alta() {
    return fecha_alta;
}
public void setFecha_alta(Date fecha_alta) {
    this.fecha_alta = fecha_alta;
}
public Date getFecha_cambios() {
    return fecha_cambios;
}
public void setFecha_cambios(Date fecha_cambios) {
    this.fecha_cambios = fecha_cambios;
}
public Date getFecha_baja() {
    return fecha_baja;
}
public void setFecha_baja(Date fecha_baja) {
    this.fecha_baja = fecha_baja;
}
```

//STRUTS-ACTION EXTENDS STRUTS.XML

```
    <action name="irSincronizar" class="action.JsonTable">
        <result name="success" type="json">/prueba.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

//STRUTS.XML

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.configuration.xml.reload" value="true"/>

 <include file="struts-usuario.xml"/>
 <include file="struts-navegacion.xml"/> 

<package name="struts" extends="struts-default,tiles-default,json-default">

</package>
```

Comment: So what's line 34? Why not include the *entire* stack trace?

Comment: public int getIdempresa() {
  return idempresa;//THIS IS LINE 34
}

Comment: Either model or reflection is broken.

Comment: i am using this example: https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag#Create_a_JSON_Action

Comment: Just a stab in the dark: whidempresa is an Integer, but getIdempresa is returning an int... You're not trying to use Java 1.4 in production are you? As David mentioned the whole stack trace would be helpful, especially the "Caused by:" message.